# Remaking the Crazy PC Program, But how to run simultaniously?

Tags: python, python-3.x

It has been a while since i have last visited stackoverflow, But i am happy to be back.

Now. Maybe some of you remember the 'Crazy PC "Virus"', (Program that constantly opens and closes your disk drive and maybe plays a song and shows a picture, But is harmless and should be made to be easy to close)

Well. For the next april fools i wanted to use this, but i cant find it.

So i decided that i needed to make it myself!

I have found some code to control the disk drive,

```
import time, pygame.cdrom as cdrom

#time.sleep(5)

while 1:
    cdrom.init()
    cd = cdrom.CD(0)
    cd.init()
    cd.eject()
    cd.quit()
    cdrom.quit()
    time.sleep(5)
```

(Thank you shubham1810)

But i am not certain if it is python 3 and it is a while, meaning (For all i know, Still a noob at code) that it wont run any other code until the while ends.

But as stated before i also want a picture to be on the screen and a sound file to play...

Have you guys got any ideas? Because i dont :(

-Natan

EDIT 1:
Ok, i have now finally been able to install pygame, and this code works on python 3. What puzzles me is that it opens the drive one time and then doesnt close it again. Does anyone know how to do this?

EDIT 2:
I have decided that this wont work and have since found a working vbs script for the cd drive opening and closing. The script is:

```
Set oWMP = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7")
Set colCDROMs = oWMP.cdromCollection
do
if colCDROMs.Count >= 1 then
For i = 0 to colCDROMs.Count -1
colCDROMs.Item(i).Eject
Next
For i = 0 to colCDROMs.Count -1
colCDROMs.Item(i).Eject
Next
End If
wscript.sleep 5000
loop
```

I will call it within python and then the picture and the song, but that still doesnt solve my problem. I still need and a picture and a song to play in the background (So without the user finding them).

Any idears?

Comment: Queue up the song and picture before you enter the while loop. Also the target computer will require python to be installed. You can target py2 or py3, though judging by the import of `pygame` and not `pygame3`, I'd say this was for 2.7.x. though I'd recommend 3.6.x

Comment: @Enfyve As i said, still a noob. How do i queue the song and picture? and i could just convert it into a .exe file, target pc shouldnt need python then, Am i right? And do you have ideas how to convert that code to 3.6.x?